# What exactly does %04 and %02 do in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

I do know how to use `%s` and in code, but I do not know how to use `%04` and `%02`. Help in simple terms would be much appreciated

ps: I am learning Python 2 in Code academy. if you need to know that.

Comment: In what context? Please read [ask]. It would probably help if you looked up the documentation for whatever function you're using those values in.

Comment: (Side note: why would you start learning Python 2 now? The reference implementation of Python 2 has already reached end-of-life. I strongly recommend going straight to Python 3.)

Answer (score 2):

That is `0-leading` formatting

```
print("%s" % 5) # 5
print("%d" % 5) # 5
print("%02d" % 5) # 05
print("%04d" % 5) # 0005
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. problem solved.

Comment: @straven3 you can accept the answer so ;)